Spring Cloud Gateway Custom Filter Handle Error Response
I have a customer filter in my spring cloud gateway and I am making a request with WebClient to validate authentication. If the response is 200 I want to continue with the execution/chain and if they response is not 200, I want to return the code I get back. My issue is I can't find a way to return the code if I can a non 200 response. Here is my code
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://" + authServiceHost + ":" + authServicePort + "/api/v1/");
        return webClient.post().uri("auth/validate-session")
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                    if (!clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                        // HOW DO I STOP EXECUTION HERE AND RETURN clientResponse.statusCode()
                        // STOP the execution of exchange here
                        // below does not work
                        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(clientResponse.statusCode());
                        return Mono.just(exchange);
                    }
                    return Mono.just(exchange);
                }).flatMap(chain::filter).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    System.out.println("First post filter");
                }));
    };
}

